# Building a partial JSON from another JSON using variables

Tags: json, react-native, react-hooks, expo, geolocation

I'm using the expo-location lib's `getCurrentPositionAsync` in my react-native project:

```
result = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync();
```

to get the current GPS position.

Now the `result` variable will hold this JSON object:

```
Object {
  "coords": Object {
    "accuracy": 603,
    "altitude": 0,
    "altitudeAccuracy": 0,
    "heading": 0,
    "latitude": 37.421988,
    "longitude": -122.0840207,
    "speed": 0,
  },
  "mocked": false,
  "timestamp": 1677233557987,
}
```

I need to save the `latitude` and `longitude` values from the `result` variable to the state variable `location` using the state function:

```
setLocation({latitude, longitude});
```

So when I run:

```
console.log(location);
```

It will show this:

```
Object {
  "latitude": 37.421988,
  "longitude": -122.0840207,
}
```

For now the only success I've had was doing this:

```
const latitude = result['coords'].latitude;
const longitude = result['coords'].longitude;

setLocation({latitude, longitude});
```

My question is - if there is a more direct way of doing this ?
like:

```
setLocation({result['coords'].latitude, result['coords'].longitude});
```

Because this doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the keys when tried to set the location state. This should work:

```
setLocation({
  latitude: result['coords'].latitude,
  longitude: result['coords'].longitude,
});
```

Alternatively, you can use destructuring to extract the latitude and longitude values from the result.coords object:

```
const { latitude, longitude } = result.coords;
setLocation({ latitude, longitude });
```

This is more cleaner way to achieve the same result.